# Changing Xpath for Data Input

Tags: power-automate

Hi I am trying to use Power Automate to enter some menial data, however I am having problems with the Xpath.

The website is set up so that I must click a button in order to add an ingredient. The for loop I used keeps referring back to the original x-path in ingredient 1. I was wondering if there was someway to keep the xpath changing with the loop.

This is what I attempted:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution. Instead of using the `x-path`, I sent key strokes. So, if the field I wanted to enter was two tabs away, I would do `{tab}{tab}`, then again send the key strokes of the variable.